# Looking to upgrade my gaming rig's graphics card

Tags: memory, graphics-card, cpu, cooling

Over the holidays I bought myself a new monitor(Acer B286HK), and while it can support very high resolutions, I am finding that my PC just isn't up to the task.

I would now like to start upgrading my gaming PC to support this nice new monitor. However, I don't want to make the mistake of getting a new graphics card that my other hardware components can't support. Especially if it really heats up my PC and I end up melting the thing.

So, below is my current make-up. I was looking at upgrading to the Nvidia GTX 970. Do I need to upgrade other components of my PC to support this graphics card?

**CPU:** Intel(R) Core™ i7-3820 Quad-Core 3.60 GHz 10MB Intel Smart Cache LGA2011 (All Venom OC Certified)

**VIDEO:** NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660 Ti 2GB 16X PCIe 3.0 Video Card (EVGA Superclocked) - *What I want to replace*

**MEMORY:** 16GB (4GBx4) DDR3/1866MHz Quad Channel Memory (Corsair XMS DDR3 1866 MHz Memory

**HDD:** 2TB (2TBx1) SATA-III 6.0Gb/s 64MB Cache 7200RPM HDD (Single Drive)

**MOTHERBOARD:** (4-Way SLI/CrossFireX Support) GIGABYTE X79-UP4 Intel X79 Chipset Quad Channel DDR3 ATX Mainboard w/ Ultra Durable 5, 7.1 HD Audio, GbLAN, 4 Gen3 PCIe x16, 2 PCIe x1 & 1 PCI

**POWERSUPPLY:** 800 Watts - Standard 80 Plus Certified Power Supply - SLI/CrossFireX

**COOLANT:** CoolIT LCS ECO II-120MM FB Water Cooler

Comment: The power requirements for the GTX 970 are clearly documented.  You don't need us to determine if you need a PSU upgrade or not

Comment: Ok, sure,  I was wondering if I just updated my graphics card would that be a waste because my ram or cpu were not also upgraded to match the requirements of higher-end settings in newer games.

Comment: What does your ram or CPU have to do with upgrading your GPU?  If you want a better GPU, then get a better GPU, those components have nothing to do with one another.

Comment: Ok great, I just didn't know that and was afraid I was going to mess things up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing you have needs upgrading. The 800Watt Power supply that you already have is absolutely fine for the gtx 970 and the specification of PC that you have.

Comment: Although an SSD would be the first thing I would get, even before graphics.